# Large animations with AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, animation

I’m trying to animate some things using frame by frame animation with AnimationDrawable.
When I load animation with this code:

```
animationHolder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.secondanimation);
frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)animationHolder.getBackground();
```

The UI become unresponsive for a couple of seconds (3-5). I guess that’s because it’s has to load a lot’s of images (*140 png’s to be precise, 400px X 300px, 50KB each*).

When I start animation, its running fine, at least on my HTC Desire.

If I run the same code in emulator I get: “OutOfMemoryError” with “bitmap size exceeded VM budget”.

What is the proper way of handling large animations? I guess there should be some kind of “lazy animation loading”. 
Does something like that already exist or I have to roll out some sort of custom view?

How other popular app’s like “Talking Tom Cat” duet?

Comment: Do you find a way to do that with OpenGl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not do animations that way... If you need to do heavy animations look into opengl. Android can't handle too many images because it uses a limited bitmap memory.

Comment: Are there any good books or on-line resources that show how to accomplish something like that?
I don’t what to learn the whole openGL stuff for a couple of simple frame by frame animations.

I know it’s a long shot but does anyone have step by step tutorial on how to run animation with openGL in android view.

I’m not making a game so I don’t have any game loops and other game related stuff.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you on that, I've walked around it on purpose :D but it shouldn't be too hard finding this, you could always make a new question asking for that instead :)